# download multiple images from server

Tags: android

Is any way to download all the images from server and save in android internal memeory.
I have a folder on server, inside this folder there are several images with unique names.
Currently I am downloading one by one from server.Is there are any way to download all the images at a time by folder URL and save in internal android phone memeory.

Comment: Run them all as async processes and save them as the finish.  You could also zip the files.

Comment: can you please provide me more detail.

Comment: see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/)

Comment: this is differnt thing.I want to download several images from the same parent path but images names are different inside this.Currently i am downloading one by one I want to discuss is there are any way to get all images on the base of parent path at a time means only by single server request.

Comment: No, you cannot request multiple things from one request unless you zip them so that they are one thing.

Comment: @JeremyMiller is right download the zip file in ascync task and store it in your sd card and then unzip it , show user progress bar while doing all this stuff

Comment: I understood,can you please provide me any sample code for this.